# Проблема с Pyinstaller и Tkcalendar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

Использую в своей программе Tkcalendar, и встретился с проблемой отображения даты после сборки через Pyinstaller. А именно, дата отображается в виде День/Месяц/Год, а надо День.Месяц.Год.

Как исправить данную проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите в документации этой библиотеки, наверняка можно менять формат дат

Comment: https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howtos.html

Comment: @dIm0n, как меня формат я знаю, и даже это есть у меня в проге, но после создания .exe файла через Pyinstaller, формат даты сбился и я не знаю как это настроить

Comment: @Victor VosMottor thanks Monica, я таким образом и менял формат даты. Также в Pyinstaller прописывал --hidden-import, т.к  без него вообще не появляется стока даты

Comment: Проблему решил! Просто заново провёл прогу через Pyinstaller и все стало ок